# using simpleheat.js for a geoheatmap with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

Trying to layer a geo-heatmap using simpleheat.js and D3.
Working off an example (https://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/803a131d4c34fde54b9fbb074341daa5). I am Successful at drawing the map  but not the points as heatmap. No error on console.log.
I get one rainbow colored blob (I overdid the radius) on the upper left corner  next to the map.
Could not find many examples and documentation on simpleheat is scant. Would appreciate any insight into this.
Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #container svg, #container canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Map Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id= "container">

</div>


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src = "node_modules/simpleheat/simpleheat.js"></script>

<script>
 //Width and height
 var w = 960;
 var h = 600;
div = d3.select("#container")
mapLayer = div.append('svg')
        .attr("id","map")
        .attr("width",w)
        .attr("height",h)

canvasLayer = div.append('canvas').attr('id', 'heatmap').attr('width', w).attr('height', h);

var canvas = canvasLayer.node(),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");


 //Define map projection
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
     .center([ -120, 37 ])
     .translate([ w/2, h/2 ])
     .scale([ 2600 ]);

   //Define path generator
var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)
var svg = d3.select("#container")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);
// read data in
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.json,"ca.json")
.defer(d3.csv, "heatCAN.csv")
.await(main)

function main (err, ca, heatCAN) {
    console.log(heatCAN)
    mapLayer
        .append('svg')
        
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(ca.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d",path)
        .attr("stroke","#000000")
        .attr("fill","#ffffff")
     //add heatmap   
    simpleheat(canvas).data(heatCAN.map(x=>[x.LON,x.LAT,x.cMort_90d])).radius(100,100).draw(0.05);

    
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: without the two data files it is hard to reproduce

Comment: Fair Enough. I put together https://github.com/AlonBenAriVA/D3MapHeatMapSimpleHeat. it has the html and a dummy  csv file with the coordinates of Sacramneto and San Francisco as well and package.json so remember to npm install in order to get simpleheat.js. If we are successful with this will put a bl.ocks of this as there arent much example, thus more will benefit.

Comment: which ca.json do you use?

Comment: After a lot of work I have the following result https://i.imgur.com/lZPSaoH.png . My suggestion is start new from the heatmap example, there is a lot wrong with your code. I have used `radius(20,20)`.

Comment: still quite at a loss. Would you mind posting your solution? I might learn something

Comment: ok, solved. this is the link on github :https://github.com/AlonBenAriVA/D3MapHeatMapSimpleHeat/tree/master. Could someoneplease assist in the zoom functionality of this.? I am trying to zoom in an out using the mouse scroll.